# How to know if user has "liked" an activity, when fetching in back-end with Getstream

Tags: getstream-io

I am currently working on a social network implementation using the getstream service, and among the current requirements is that users can "like" the activities posted there.

I want to know how to know in the back-end if a user has given like to the list of activities that are obtained by getting a feed.

The problem is that for privacy reasons, we are getting the list of posts of a user (which is NOT the "users" feed) from the back-end, and we can't find a way to reference the user who is requesting that list of activities, so that the configuration `{reactions: { own: true } }` works correctly.

Any idea?